# Partition By over Two Columns in Row_Number function

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, row-number, partition-by

I am trying to RANK the records using the following query:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by 
TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate 
order by TW.EMPL_ID,TW.Effective_Bdate) RN,
TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate,Effective_BDate from 
TT_EMPLOYEE_WORKDAY TW
where TW.HR_DOMAIN_CODE = 'SGP'
```

However the resultant Row_Number computed column only displays partition for the first column. Ideally I expected to have the same value for Row_Number where the partition by column data is identical.

Any clue where I might be going wrong?

USING RANK or DENSE RANK isn't an option as I want to identify all such rows for multiple employee where EMPL_ID, HR_DEPT_ID and Transfer_StartDate are same (RN=1)

```
Sample data:
RN  AON_EMPL_ID   HR_DEPT_ID    Transfer_Startdate  Effective_BDate
1   0100690       69895             01/01/2017       2017-01-01
2   0100690       69895             01/01/2017       2017-01-03
3   0100690       69895             01/01/2017       2017-01-04
```

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help you explain what you want.

Comment: Sample data as ddl+dml and desired result would help...

Comment: because you `Order by` the result, it will disorder the `Partition` part, try to `Order by TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate,TW.RN` or remove the `Order by`

Comment: Even without order by used in the last line, the RN number varies. It should be 1 as first three columns used in Partition By has same data.

Comment: where is `TW.EMPL_ID`, you might make mistake to `TW.AON_EMPL_ID`?

Comment: @LONG Please ignore that, I have modified the query to avoid posting proprietary information. The query is syntactically correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added Sample data. Desired result is RN should 1 for all three rows.

Comment: @Sharktooth you are talking about `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`, not `ROW_NUMBER`, replace the later one with the either of the former one, and depends on how you want to show the 2nd place data

Comment: @LONG Rank won't work for more than one employee as the first proposed solution below suggests.

Comment: @Sharktooth Check my update, I think you only need to `order by` the `Effective Date` from the result, which is not supposed to make any contribution to the function

Answer (score 2):

expanding sample data to:

```
create table t (
    aon_empl_id varchar(16)
  , hr_dept_id varchar(16)
  , Transfer_Startdate date
  , Effective_bdate date
);
insert into t values 
 ('0100690','69895','01/01/2017','2017-01-01')
,('0100690','69895','01/01/2017','2017-01-03')
,('0100690','69895','01/01/2017','2017-01-04')
,('0200700','69895','01/01/2016','2016-01-01')
,('0200700','69895','01/01/2016','2016-01-03')
,('0200700','69896','01/01/2017','2017-01-04')
,('0200700','69896','01/01/2017','2017-01-04');
```

using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)

```
select top 1 with ties
    aon_empl_id
  , hr_dept_id
  , Transfer_Startdate = convert(char(10),Transfer_Startdate,120)
  , Effective_bdate    = convert(char(10),Effective_bdate,120)
from t
order by row_number() over (
      partition by aon_empl_id, hr_dept_id, Transfer_Startdate 
      order by Effective_bdate
      )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KOIZ42069

returns:

```
+-------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| aon_empl_id | hr_dept_id | Transfer_Startdate | Effective_bdate |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|     0100690 |      69895 | 2017-01-01         | 2017-01-01      |
|     0200700 |      69895 | 2016-01-01         | 2016-01-01      |
|     0200700 |      69896 | 2017-01-01         | 2017-01-04      |
+-------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

---

Alternative using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
;with cte as (
select
    rn = row_number() over (
      partition by aon_empl_id, hr_dept_id, Transfer_Startdate 
      order by Effective_bdate
    )
  , aon_empl_id
  , hr_dept_id
  , Transfer_Startdate = convert(char(10),Transfer_Startdate,120)
  , Effective_bdate    = convert(char(10),Effective_bdate,120)
from t tw
)

select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

returns:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| rn | aon_empl_id | hr_dept_id | Transfer_Startdate | Effective_bdate |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
|  1 |     0100690 |      69895 | 2017-01-01         | 2017-01-01      |
|  1 |     0200700 |      69895 | 2016-01-01         | 2016-01-01      |
|  1 |     0200700 |      69896 | 2017-01-01         | 2017-01-04      |
+----+-------------+------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This works well for one employee which I used as a sample record, over a number of employees it will repeat the rank for example for the above set of row all will be 1 but for the next employee it will be 2. I want to have RN = 1 for all Employee records where empl_id, hr_dept_id, transfer_startdate is same.

Comment: @Sharktooth You haven't explained when you want it to not be `1`. What part goes in the `partition`, e.g. `(partition by aon_empl_id order by aon_empl_id, hr_dept_id, Transfer_Startdate)`

Comment: partition by would have the following columns: aon_empl_id, hr_dept_id, Transfer_Startdate if these columns have a distinct unique value for more than one row then RN should increment by 1 otherwise it should remain 1.

Comment: @Sharktooth That sounds like what you've already done. But I took another stab at it and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
RANK() over (partition by   --or DENSE_RANK()
TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate 
order by TW.EMPL_ID,TW.Effective_Bdate) RN,
TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate,Effective_BDate from 
TT_EMPLOYEE_WORKDAY TW
where TW.HR_DOMAIN_CODE = 'SGP'
```

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT 
RANK() over (partition by   --or DENSE_RANK()
TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate 
order by TW.EMPL_ID) RN,
TW.EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate,Effective_BDate from 
TT_EMPLOYEE_WORKDAY TW
where TW.HR_DOMAIN_CODE = 'SGP'
Order by RN,TW.Effective_Bdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code appears to be working:

```
SELECT 
dense_rank() over (partition by AON_EMPL_ID 
order by AON_EMPL_ID,HR_DEPT_ID,Transfer_StartDate) RN,
TW.AON_EMPL_ID,TW.HR_DEPT_ID,TW.Transfer_Startdate,Effective_BDate from 
TT_AON_EMPLOYEE_WORKDAY TW
where TW.HR_DOMAIN_CODE = 'SGP'
```

Apparently, I just need to partition by AON_EMPL_ID and everything else should go to Order By clause.